# SpaceX Super Heavy booster: Is it publicly known whether the failure of one engine to start prior to liftoff will result in a pad abort?

Tags: failure, abort, spacex-super-heavy

> Elon Musk, SpaceX’s founder and CEO, tweeted minutes later that engineers turned off one of the booster’s 33 engines just before ignition, and another engine “stopped itself.”
>
> “So 31 engines fired overall,” Musk tweeted. “But still enough engines to reach orbit!”

Source: [Spaceflight Now article](https://spaceflightnow.com/2023/02/09/spacex-test-fires-31-engines-on-starships-gigantic-super-heavy-booster/)

One engine out *after liftoff* for this beast of a booster is unlikely to result in mission failure. But is it publicly known whether one engine out *on the pad* will cause a pad abort (meaning a shutdown of the running engines and termination of the launch attempt)?

Note: Not looking for guesses or unsubstantiated answers.

Comment: This question needs to be closed. There is nothing specific in this statement: "one engine out on the pad". There are hundreds of different diagnostics and pre-flight checks. Some of these checks or combinations of those can rise to the level of mission abort.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance you couldn't be more wrong. It's very straightforward - does anyone know if the booster will be allowed to lift off with one engine out, or not? For most vehicles, the answer is no. But "most vehicles" don't have so many engines.

Comment: I could be wrong, the community cannot.

Comment: Organic Marble - "t's very straightforward " Can you describe the possible diagnostics failure that would practically mean - "engine out". How would you know it is out until the ignition started?

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance For shuttle, it was chamber pressure less than 90% of the nominal value.  If all three engines didn't attain > that, the SRBs were not ignited and the holddown posts were not blown. A simple binary go/no-go criterion on each engine.

Comment: "chamber pressure less than 90% " - does not mean "engine out"

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance that was literally the definition of it in shuttle for proceeding with the launch. You're not helping your argument here. Understandable, because it's wrong.

Comment: The partial loss of performance is very different than the potential for a catastrophic failure (engine explosion).

Comment: Agreed, and nothing in what I wrote references a catastrophic failure in any way. In fact, the title says  "failure to start".

Comment: Too bad Tim Dodd isn't hanging around here anymore.

Comment: @ErinAnne I am pretty sure that user is not Tim Dodd.  The profile says "part time fake of full time fake astronaut". And it was discussed in comments somewhere.

Comment: thanks for the correction; deleting the ping

Comment: @ErinAnne I am a big fan of Tim Dodd. I watch his videos on his channel theEverydayAstronaut. I am so happy he got accepted for DearMoon. Just wanted to say.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, considering the aspirational launch cadence of launching the same booster multiple times per hour. So, if they perform a pad abort, they need to destack the Starship, park it next to the pad, get the booster off the pad, get another booster on the pad, and stack the Starship back on top … it might be easier to just launch it and risk mission failure but at least have the pad clear for the next launch. Full and Rapid Reuse really changes some priorities and trade-offs in weird and unusual ways.

Comment: … or alternatively, fix and potentially swap the offending engine within minutes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I was hoping you would weigh in, I figured if anyone knew the answer, it would be you. Eventually we will find out. My guess is "just launch it and risk mission failure" - for example, if preflight analysis shows the ascent could succeed with 2 out off the pad, they might be go to launch with one out. I've read that early shuttle thinking was that they would launch with some level of redundancy lost (not engines, but other systems) but that went away.

Comment: Did they launch today with 3 out? If someone can confirm that, it could be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to remarks from Mr. Musk summarized in an article on [Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/science/2023/05/elon-musk-provides-detailed-review-of-starships-first-launch-and-whats-next/), at least for the test flight on 4/20/23, the vehicle was allowed to lift off with three engines out, which was the maximum allowed number of engines out to proceed with the launch.

> When the rocket lifted off, there were three engines whose ignition was terminated because the flight software did not deem them "healthy enough" to bring to full thrust. That left 30 of the Super Heavy first stage's 33 engines in good condition, which is the minimum allowable number for liftoff.